# How to use the original filename in a multi file template in resharper?

Tags: templates, resharper

I have a multi file template in resharper and I can use `$NAME$` macro to get the name of the original file to use to name the other files in the template.  But I also want to use the `$NAME$` of the original file in the content of the other file template.

Is this possible?  I can't see a macro which seems suitable for the internal variables as onlt the Current File Name seems available.

Anyone know if this is possible or how I might workaround this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you may create a parameter `$FILENAME$` (macro "Current file name without extension") in the first file e.g. in the comments, like:

```
class Foo
{
     //$FILENAME$
}
```

Then you may call this parameter in other files of the multifile template - this parameter will contain the name of the first file since the first file will be generated before other ones.

Comment: Thanks. This is what we gave done although not in the comments. This is a good idea and I'll change or implementation to do this. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't a macro that will give you this. I've added a feature request that you can vote on and track (and more specific detail as to what your requirements are would be useful) - http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-415055

It is possible to [write your own macros](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/4.04+Live+Template+Macros+%28R8%29) as part of a plugin, but there isn't a sure-fire way of getting the name of the first document in the created file set. The `IHotspotSessionContext` instance that is passed to the macro via `IHotspotSession.Context` property includes an enumerable of `IDocument`, from which you can get `IDocument.Moniker`, which will be the full path for file based documents. However, there's no guarantee of the order of the enumerable - it's backed by a hashset. You *might* be able to rely on implementation details (small set, no removes) to be able to use the first document as the original, but there is really no guarantee of this.

Comment: Thanks Matt! That's awesome. I'll update the feature request tomorrow with my example.